# Navigation App for Browser

Tags: navigation

There are many navigation apps which describes the point of the user to the intended location. Is there any self updating mobile like navigation app or service for browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Well you would have to have a GPS on the computer running the browser for it to self-update to your current location.  Otherwise the only way a browser running on your computer would know where you are is if you tell it.